# Compare 2 google worksheets with apps scripts

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm just making sure there is not an easier way to do this.  I need to copy a worksheet from one g-sheet to another. Not a big deal.  Then I have to compare that worksheet, to another worksheet that is a week older. There will be duplicate rows, I need to only delete the duplicate rows from the current sheet. I can't find any compare sheet in the API.  Do I have to loop through all the rows to achieve this?

Thanks! Any suggestions would be great!

Rudy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you do but do it using arrays otherwise the script might be quite slow.

You just have to use `sourceSheet.getDataRange().getValues()` to get the "array image" of your source sheet (get this one by its spreadsheet ID + sheet name) and do the same with the sheet to compare and then loop accross both sheets looking for duplicates.

Each row that is not a duplicate should be pushed in a third array that will be the combination of the 2 others.

At the end, use `setValues(resultArray)` to write it back to a new sheet.

Comment: Thank you Serge! Great info.  I might come back if my script doesn't work. But it seems pretty straight forward.  Rudy

Comment: Hello, So I think I'm close.  There are a ton of good examples.  Mine is a pretty easy request.  Copy all the data from one worksheet to the second one. I did notice a couple of issues. First, I'm creating a sheet, loading it with data from a csv, then creating a new sheet. And I'm using a IMPORT on my cell string.

Comment: Hello All! Here is my code.  I just need to copy, as I am not comparing any more.  I'm not sure what I can put for a condition, i just need to copy values. Maybe to make sure a value is there? Here is my **CODE** for ( r = 1; r < firstArray.length; r++) { // iterate the first col of masterSheet
      if(firstArray[r][0]=='Some condition'){ // if value in the first column == 'some condition get the second column cell in the new array (here you could change what you want to get)
        dataList.push([firstArray[r][1]])
  } **CODE**   Any help would be great!

Comment: Please don't ask questions in comments...they are hard to read and not very visible-Start a new question if you want. Thx.