# How to compare two column in a spreadsheet

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I have 30 columns and 1000 rows, I would like to compare column1 with another column. IF the value dont match then I would like to colour it red. Below is a small dataset in my spreadsheet:

```
      A       B      C      D   E   F    ...
1    name   sName   email 
2
3
.
n
```

Because I have a large dataset and I want to storing my columns in a array, the first row is heading. This is what I have done, however when testing I get empty result, can someone correct me what I am doing wrong?

```js
var index = [];
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();

function col(){
    var data = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
  for (var i = 1; i <= data.length; i++) {
        te = index[i] = data[1];
        Logger.log(columnIndex[i])
        if (data[3] != data[7]){
            // column_id.setFontColor('red');  <--- I can set the background like this
        }
    }  
}
```

From the code you can see I am scanning whole spreadsheet data[1] get the heading and in if loop `(data[3] != data[7])` compare two columns. I do have to work on my colour variable but that can be done once I get the data that I need.

Comment: @pnuts yes your correct, however I would like this spreadsheet to have other complicated  functionalities (this being the simple one).

Answer (score 0):

Try to check this [tutorial](https://mashe.hawksey.info/2013/07/google-spreadsheet-how-to-compare-two-strings-and-highlight-the-differences/) if it can help you with your problem. This tutorial use a [Google AppsScript](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/overview) to compare the two columns. If differences are found, the script should point these out. If no differences are found at all, the script should put out the text "[id]". Just customize this code for your own function.

Here is the code used to achieve this kind of comparison

```
function stringComparison(s1, s2) {
  // lets test both variables are the same object type if not throw an error
  if (Object.prototype.toString.call(s1) !== Object.prototype.toString.call(s2)){
    throw("Both values need to be an array of cells or individual cells")
  }
  // if we are looking at two arrays of cells make sure the sizes match and only one column wide
  if( Object.prototype.toString.call(s1) === '[object Array]' ) {
    if (s1.length != s2.length || s1[0].length > 1 || s2[0].length > 1){
      throw("Arrays of cells need to be same size and 1 column wide");
    }
    // since we are working with an array intialise the return
    var out = [];
    for (r in s1){ // loop over the rows and find differences using diff sub function
      out.push([diff(s1[r][0], s2[r][0])]);
    }
    return out; // return response
  } else { // we are working with two cells so return diff
    return diff(s1, s2)
  }
}

function diff (s1, s2){
  var out = "[ ";
  var notid = false;
  // loop to match each character
  for (var n = 0; n < s1.length; n++){
    if (s1.charAt(n) == s2.charAt(n)){
      out += "–";
    } else {
      out += s2.charAt(n);
      notid = true;
    }
out += " ";
  }
  out += " ]"
  return (notid) ? out :  "[ id. ]"; // if notid(entical) return output or [id.]
}
```

For more information, just check the tutorial link above and this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24331979/compare-2-google-worksheets-with-apps-scripts) on how to compare two Spreadsheets.